# GCM and Smack API

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to connect to Cloud Connection Server of GCM using Smack API. My code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("gcm.googleapis.com","5235");
        config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSocketFactory(SocketFactory.getDefault());
        Connection conn = new XMPPConnection(config);
        conn.connect();
        conn.login(Config.GCM_SENDER_ID, Config.GCM_API_KEY);
```

However I got connection fail error and XMPPException error. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add more information. Code alone is not enough. It would be a good idea to include the stacktrace and type of the XMPPException and some log ouput.

Comment: Has your project id (aka sender id) been whitelisted by Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CCS documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#usage):

> CCS requires a Transport Layer Security (TLS) connection. That means the XMPP client must initiate a TLS connection. For example in smack, you would call setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory), similar to “old style SSL” XMPP connections and https.

Therefore use the following in your code:

```
config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
```